# Code missing after '<' (less than) in the raw query builder codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following code:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM m_buy a left join m_brand b on b.id = a.id_brand 
Where DATE_FORMAT(a.date, '%H') < '13' 
And a.status = '$stat' 
Group by a.id_brand order by a.id_brand ")
```

But when want to check the query using `$this->db->last_query();`, the code missing after '<' (less than), the code missing just right after `where  DATE_FORMAT(a.date, '%H')`, if I move the status statement behind the date format, the code become `a.status = '$stat' and DATE_FORMAT(a.date, '%H')`, `13` and afterward missing.

how is it possible ?

Comment: Please show the actual PHP code.  It's hard to figure things out looking at a raw query string from another context.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thats the actual code, i use `$this->db->last_query("SELECT * FROM m_buy a left join m_brand b on b.id = a.id_brand  where  DATE_FORMAT(a.date, '%H') < '13' and a.status = '$stat' group by a.id_brand order by a.id_brand");`
thats it

Comment: 13 is number you don't have to put single quotes

Comment: date_format returning string so try like this  (CAST(DATE_FORMAT(a.date, '%H')  AS UNSIGNED) > 3)

Comment: you are getting that error as you are using string to check with date. remove the single quotes around the 13 and check

Comment: @AravindhGopi I did all your suggest, but still not work, the code still missing after <, if I change the  '<' become '>' or '=', it works. this makes me crazy

Comment: try to compile your code in phpMyadmin first, for that use `$this->db->get_compiled_select(yourTableName)` comment `$this->db->get` and `$this->da->from()`. Your code is good, though 13 have single quotes

Comment: @AravindhGopi my query above is just sub query, so my query is like 'select * from table_1 a left join (mycodeabove) b'.
strange thing is, before I using variable to the code, my code works, but when I edited the code, suddenly '<' become problem, its funny how it suddenly error

Comment: Well have you tried to print your query as i mentioned above?? You need to post your full php code don't just write , post your exact function/code.

Comment: strange think is single quotes and doubles quotes not escaped properly . @bayuwibisana

Comment: in my production, my code works with singe quotes, cause date_format return string, i will post my exact function @JYoThI

Comment: `$this->db->query("select c.id,c.nama,(case  when d.jumlah is null then '0' else d.jumlah end) as jumlah 
from m_brand c left join 
(SELECT b.id,b.nama,sum(a.jumlah) as jumlah FROM m_pembelian a left join m_brand b on b.id = a.id_brand where a.po is not null and DATE_FORMAT(a.tgl, '%Y-%m-%d') = '$tanggal' and DATE_FORMAT(a.tgl, '%H') < '13' and a.is_published = '0' and a.status = '0' group by a.id_brand order by a.id_brand) d on d.id = c.id where c.status = '1'");` @AravindhGopi

Comment: @JYoThI my code above is the real one, but nevermind, I will use between instead.

Comment: still your showing raw query . as you said above comment your concatenate the subquery . i don't see any variable like that . @bayuwibisana

Comment: @JYoThI but if I change the '<' to '=' or '>', the code show properly

Comment: so change like this and try  '13' > DATE_FORMAT(a.tgl, '%H')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not missing.

As you're printing the query in a browser, it interpets the `<` as the start of an HTML tag and renders it as such. It is there, you just don't see it.

Use "View source", or encode the output via `htmlspecialchars()` to make it render properly.